# Is there a limit to safe downhill speed on a bike

Tags: speed, downhill

[image]I have a very steep hill on my route which levels out after about 2 km. The first quarter is extremely steep and shortly after I enter it the bike skips around a little bit and by the time I'm at the bottom I'm gripping the handle bars and working pretty hard to keep it under control.

Is this a normal issue or is it indicative of problems with the bike? It happens both with my mountain bike and the touring bike. Less on the 29'er mountain bike perhaps due to the wider tyres and less twitchy handling.

There is a lot of acceleration right from the start going down.

Clarification:- I'm not concerned with other people's safety or traffic, my question is more about at what speed does my bike become unhandleable and/or fall to pieces.

Comment: 45% gradient - would love to see that Strava segment

Comment: Please add single word about road surface type and condition, plus speed you reach. On even surface, with well-balanced wheels there should be no wobbling.

Comment: it's sealed road, not the best but no potholes. No idea on the speed I reach.... pretty fast.

Comment: @krzyski that assumes a *perfectly* even surface. Clipping a loose stone or bit of litter can set set up oscillations depending on how well you react to the intial effect, not forgetting that the steering behaves dfferently with speed

Comment: Steepest sealed road I've ever seen was *signposted* as 30%

Comment: A contour map would give an idea of the actual gradient.

Comment: @ChrisH I cannot agree, Even imperfect, but reasonably well surface should not result in behaviour requiring "working pretty hard to keep it under control". Gravel, debris and litter for sure can be source ot this problem. The faster you ride, the harder is to turn, bike sholud be more "stable". I'm curious if OP case could be shimmy.

Comment: @andy256 I would say 45% with short steeper bits is roughly accurate, I'm not in the first World, we don't even have street name signs here let alone gradient ones.

Comment: @krzyski I don't think so, it's more like it's just barely touching the road and skipping around a little bit like it's almost airborne and bouncing slightly, that's what it feels like anyway, perhaps 'wobble' wasn't a good description.

Comment: @Kilisi Leaving alone your original question, what kind of brakes do you use and for how long it lasts?

Comment: @krzyski I don't use the brakes

Comment: If you don't use the brakes, this grade is not 45%.   Even a 15% grade gets crazy fast quick.  Please provide the location of this road, coordinates from google maps would be perfect.

Comment: I'll see if I can find it on google map

Comment: @Kilisi can normal vehicles get up it? If so it's almost certainly considerably less than 45%.  The steepest street in the world according the Guiness book of records is around 38% (in New Zealand).

Comment: If you can cycle up it, I can't believe that it's 45% for 500 metres.  That's probably beyond even professional hill-climb specialists.

Comment: I found it on google map but nothing about gradient from the view it gives me. I'll take a couple of photos on the weekend.

Comment: @WillVousden no idea on that, yes I cycle up it, I've probably overestimated the distance for the steepest part though, but it's a long hard slog in highest gear. I'd take a pic now but it's night time. I'm running it through my mind right now, I still believe my gradient estimate is correct, notwithstanding whatever you guys say, no offense. I'll definitely put pictures up.

Comment: http://www.foxnews.com/travel/2014/03/03/worlds-steepest-roads.html shows the world's steepest streets are under 40%   A fit cyclist can lift the front wheel on a flat road, let alone a climb.   Even 15% looks super steep when standing at the bottom!  Please show us where in the world is this climb.

Comment: @Criggie already said I will mate, you guys can go on about it all you want, but it's night time I can't take a pic right now, so be patient. I do know the difference between 15% and 45% believe it or not.

Comment: The three limiting factors for downhill stability are bike geometry (and we'll include tires there), road surface condition, and cyclist skill.  Oh, and load on the bike (bags or backpack) is also a significant factor.  One thing to keep in mind is that you can be perfectly stable going down and then hit a small bump and begin to oscillate madly.

Comment: @Criggie in a low enough gear you don't have to be that fit to lift the front wheelon the flat.  It's disconcerting when you're riding an unfamiliar bike and the smallest chainring is much lower than you're used to.

Comment: Yes, c. It is the final speed limit.

Comment: @Móż I get so close sometimes but I find the air being compressed and setting things alight is rather off-putting. I'll stick at 0.5c for my commute.

Comment: A 45% grade would not be physically possible to climb without clipless pedals or pedal clips. Your full weight on one pedal, in the lowest gear available for a typical bicycle, is not enough to propel the bike forward on even a 30% grade hill. You wouldn't even be able to keep the *back* wheel on the ground while pedaling, from having to lean so far forward.

Comment: @Criggie you guys were right, I took some pics on the way home and it isn't 45%, had to turn them a bit so I could get an idea of the angle, probably because I was on the bike on the slope when I took them and there's only two walls to judge angle on and only the bottom has a foot path. Will put the pic in the question even though it's irrelevant. The 500 metres was about right though.

Comment: Good pics. The hill looks like it's about 1 in 5, or 20% A solid little hill :-)

Comment: @andy256 Certainly builds up a lot of speed on the way down, probably feels so steep because I go up right at the end of my commute, my house is about 200 m past the top

Comment: That looks like a wicked wee climb - the best(worst) near me are 17-18% for 200 metres.

Comment: Yeah, I would guess about 20%.  The thing to do is to look at the walls in the picture, and estimate the height vs length of a segment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47178/discussion-on-question-by-kilisi-is-there-a-limit-to-safe-downhill-speed-on-a-bi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything like a **specific** safe speed for going downhill. From my experience there are many reasons for a bike becoming unhandlable when going downhill:

**your bike**: i'd say the main factors that enable you to go downhill fast *& safe* are:

- frame & fork: a super stiff carbon frame or an aluminium frame tend to be less shakey on a fast downhill ride. the same is valid for the fork. however, the stiffer your frame, the more sensitive it is to bumps etc.
- wheels: aero designed wheels (i.e. "high" rims and flat spokes) allow higher levels of control at high speeds.
- tyres: the wider the more friction and more absorption of bumps.
- suspension: generally hinder control at high speeds, however if the road is very uneven it might still be of benefit nontheless
- handle bar: wider handle bars and a longer stem make your bike less twitchy at high speeds
- stance: the wider your bottom bracket / the pedals, the smaller becomes the issue of balance at high speeds

**fear / the size of your balls**: right after the hardware, i'd say the software (as in your brains) determine a safe downhill speed.

**the road**: not gonna go to details here, that has been discussed in may ways in the comments.

*summing up*: if your bike is properly set up and well maintained, i don't assume it would just fall apart when going fast.

Comment: I'm going to agree with this, it's more a balls factor than anything else. With a decent bike anyway I guess.

Comment: https://youtu.be/YfMQdFGTKAs

Comment: now thats a giant pair... made of titanium!

Comment: @JohnP Those two commentators were responsible for the famous UK throat medication shortage of 2011-12.

Comment: With help and the right bike you can just keep going it seems. https://www.google.co.uk/amp/velonews.competitor.com/2016/09/news/ca-woman-rides-her-bicycle-147-mph-a-new-world-record_420507/amp?client=safari

Comment: @Chris excellent, I'll try and crouch down into a faster stance. The only thing worrying me was that the bike might not handle it. Would be unpleasant to have a tyre explode,  or spokes spin themselves off due to centrifugal forces or a bearing overheat and seize or something.

Answer (score 7):

The maximum safe speed is the speed where you still have control you think is needed.

There are levels of control

- Can you stop if a car suddenly reverses out of a driveway?
  This is the highest level of control; it means we'd never exceed about **25kph (16mph)** on the flat. Obviously we frequently exceed that, and so we're trusting that such intrusions into our "road space" will not occur *on this ride*.
- Can you swerve to avoid a small child or animal that suddenly runs onto the road?
  Since such intruders are notoriously unpredictable, we also need to brake *and* swerve. If I know there are kids / dogs on the loose, I slow down to that 25kph level, or slower. But if it's reasonably open road I figure it's reasonably safe to clock **40kph (25mph)**. I've encountered oncoming cars in my lane as I round a bend on a descent at this speed, and there's plenty of time to evaluate my options, brake, and take evasive action (time flows *really* slowly in such cases).
- If the road is *really* clear, i.e. you can see well to the sides, and a long way in front.
  In this case we can easily do **60kph (35mph)**. Around this point (and faster) some rider / bike combinations can experience shaking, which can be quite frightening. You need to experiment a bit to learn what's going on. In many cases resting your knee against the frame seems to dampen the shakes. In other cases I've had success *relaxing* my grip on the handlebars - this seems to suggest that it was my fear of death grip on the bars causing the wobbles :-)
- Ok the road is clear, and you're feeling lucky. How fast can you go?
  If we keep going faster, it seems we pass the zone where the speed wobbles occur. If you are not a pro (being paid to do it), and are not confident, or are just a sensible person **don't do it**. However, I can confess to cracking 120kph (70mph) on a descent on a road bike. I found that as I went faster the bike became more stable, I'm guessing from the gyroscopic effect of the wheels. The same effect seemed to make turns more difficult. The first time I also found it was *extremely* hard to see properly, since I wasn't wearing any eye protection. And it took over 400 meters to stop on the flat. We can be sure that if any of the above mentioned road intrusions occurred then I would have been toast.

After all that, given the pictures you've posted, I would recommend at top speed of **30 to 40kph (16 to 25mph)**, because it looks like a residential area. Even that may be too fast, especially because of the incline, which means your center of gravity is higher and so you have less braking capacity.

Comment: Good answer, I'm discounting all the safety tips, my question was more about at what speed does my bike become unhandleable and/or fall to pieces. Cars aren't a problem, I go faster than them downhill on a not busy road which is straight with no turns for 2 k. Realistically if this section had a turn in it, I don't think I'd make a corner without using brakes. Which would put my MTB out of it, since it doesn't have any.

Comment: @Kilisi cars aren't a problem till that one day a car IS a problem.

Comment: @andy256 totally agree.  Thinking of a long local 10% grade, I'm happy to bomb down it at 50 km/h.  But the next hill over has a much shorter and narrower 17% grade and I'll actively brake more to keep the speed at about 25 km/h.   So width of road, view lines, and runout space is critical to "safe speed"

Comment: @Criggie we all got to die one day, I've done it and came out the other side, doesn't worry me anymore. Will get what I can out of life while I have it.

Comment: @Kilisi That's fine, just as long as you're not putting anyone else in danger!

Comment: @Kilisi: You are out of your mind to go down that hill with no brakes. OUT OF YOUR MIND. I refuse to even _ride_ a bike without brakes, after one incident that I would rather not experience again.

Comment: @FighterJet my background is with motor bikes, I'm used to high speeds. But at the speeds I reach on the bicycle, I reckon if I had to jam on the brakes in a hurry I'd lose control anyway.

Comment: @Kil: Sure, but what do you do when there's a stop sign at the bottom?

Comment: @FighterJet when did they put that in? I been riding this route for months.

Comment: @Kilisi: I suppose I should ask more generally: what do you do when there's a stop sign in front of you? Or even more generally, what do you do when you need to stop for _any_ reason? Stick your foot in the rear tire? Drag your feet on the ground?

Comment: @FighterJet just drag my foot on the ground on the mountain bike, my touring bike has good brakes. But normally I don't stop for stop signs anyway, those are for cars and other things. I slow down or stop for vehicles or pedestrians, but not for signs or lights.

Comment: In most of the world, stop signs, traffic signals, and most traffic laws apply to bicycles as much as they do cars, and if you break those laws, you're looked down upon just like drivers who break the rules of the road are. Just saying.

Comment: @FighterJet I'm in the third World, laws are a bit of a joke, the cops don't even learn them. Had a cop tell me I'm not allowed on the road at all. Gave him $5 and told him to bugger off.

Answer (score 5):

High speed stability can be dramatically affected by the geometry of the bike in question. There's a chance that the head angle on your 29'er is slacker which should give greater stability.

I know that on a car at certain rpm's you can get vibration through the car if a wheel is not correctly balanced. You might want to check over your wheels and make sure spoke tension is correct for safety's sake.

I don't know what bike you're riding and I'm not a road rider really but perhaps there's something in your posture that can aid stability. On an MTB you'd hang further out the back to keep your weight centred over the bottom bracket.

Comment: Wider MTB handlebars help a lot with control and therefore confidence.

Comment: ON re-reading, hanging your body weight backwards helps with braking on a downhill.  It also gives you more of a triangle of rigidity through the arms and across your handlebars.  HOWEVER on a road bike with no suspension, moving your weight back can produce weird oscillations in the bike at high speed, AKA shimmy or Death Wobble.  The answer is to press a knee lightly against your top tube or to move *forward* when not braking.   http://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/shimmy.html

Comment: I suspected things might be a little different on a road bike. I'm pretty envious on my commute at the speeds of road bikes but not enough to buy one yet.

Comment: @Criggie, makes sense, I'm on a touring bike with flat handlebars and no suspension, I tend to feel safer leaning a bit forwards, but I stand with my butt just touching the seat on the pedals to take the bumps better and let air resistance slow me a bit.

Comment: @Criggie: Hanging backwards on a downhill helps when braking on soft ground. On a road it will prove counter-productive to reduce the load on the front wheel  because the front wheel will begin to oscillate between ~45-60kmh, (the reason some motorbikes have steering dampers). I have experienced this and it is a very awful sensation because it is almost impossible to stop the shimmy.

Comment: @carel then we're in agreement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to safe downhill speed on your bike. The limit is when you come off your bike. In which case even a low speed crash of 20 to 30 mph can be pretty nasty on chip and seal type surfaces or where there are obstacles (oncoming traffic anyone?).

You can ride a modern road bike up to 60 mph, even a little more but I would say that it is not safe to ride at that speed with nothing but spandex and a lightweight crash helmet.

Comment: You're right - its possible to get wiped out by standing still, in the wrong place at the wrong time.   OP's question was about safe maximum velocity, not falling, so subtly different.

Comment: Well I think terminal velocity is around 200kph, the upper maximum speed for a road bike is probably around 125kph on the roads that exist. On a good road bike speeds in the 100kph range shouldn't be a problem on a long 10% gradient with a good surface but you'd have little chance of stopping if a dog ran out in front of you.